# Thread Sequence using AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#

I am having a Collection(List) object which contains Enums and assigned with one class. I have a main class with operations relating with the Enums Defined. I am creating 3 threads and calling the same method of the above class.I want to sequnce btw the threads in different ways, but my threads are not getting moving as required. Attaching the sample code

```
for(interalIterator=0;interalIterator<coll.NodeList.Count;interalIterator++)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(threadid +"  : " + "Waitting");

    while(coll.processcompleted.WaitOne())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : Thread Load port ID " + 
                  coll.NodeList[interalIterator].LoadPortID);             
        if (carrieroperation == Operations.L1)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (coll.NodeList[interalIterator].LoadPortID == p.LoadPorts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + 
                            "Entered  operation for LP:" + 
                            p.LoadPorts.ToString());
                    SetNextEnum(coll, interalIterator);

                    //CheckCollectionEnd(interalIterator);
                    coll.processcompleted.Set();
                    Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + 
                           "Released Thread - Load operation for LP:" +
                            p.LoadPorts.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        else if (carrieroperation == Operations.P1)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if(coll.NodeList[interalIterator].LoadPortID == p.LoadPorts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + 
                        "Entered  operation for LP:" + 
                        p.LoadPorts.ToString());
                    SetNextEnum(coll, interalIterator);
                    coll.processcompleted.Set();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (carrieroperation == Operations.C1)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if(coll.NodeList[interalIterator].LoadPortID == p.LoadPorts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + 
                        "Entered operation for LP:" + 
                        p.LoadPorts.ToString());
                    SetNextEnum(coll, interalIterator);
                    coll.processcompleted.Set();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + "Loop End");
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The request was to sequence between the thread, Solved the issue with the following code, hope this will help somebody. Thanks to all for the help..

```
 public class Node
    {
        public CarrierOperations _string;
        public int _int;     

        public CarrierOperations OperationName
        {
            get { return _string; }
            set { _string = value; }
        }
        public int LoadPortID
        {
            get { return _int; }
            set { _int = value; }

        }
        public Node(CarrierOperations _s, int _v)
        {
            _string = _s;
            _int = _v;         
        }           

    }
 public class Node
    {
        public CarrierOperations _string;
        public int _int;     

        public CarrierOperations OperationName
        {
            get { return _string; }
            set { _string = value; }
        }
        public int LoadPortID
        {
            get { return _int; }
            set { _int = value; }

        }
        public Node(CarrierOperations _s, int _v)
        {
            _string = _s;
            _int = _v;         
        }           

    }

    public class ThreadLoops
    {

        SequenceCollections collection = new SequenceCollections();

        Parameters[] para = new Parameters[3];
        RunTest[] testArray = new RunTest[3];
        public ThreadLoops()
        {
           para = CreateParameters();           
           testArray = CreateTestObject(para);
        }
        public void Execute()
        {
            collection = CreateSequnce();
           Parameters[] param = CreateParameters();

            testArray = CreateTestObject(param);
            //Creation Threads and registring for test case completed events for each single test case.
            for (int index = 0 ; index < 3; index++)
            {
                Thread testCaseExecuteThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecuteSingleTest));
                testCaseExecuteThread.Start(testArray[index]);
                Console.WriteLine("Started RunTest ");                
                //Sleep 5 sec before starting next thread.

            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
           // testArray[2].TestParams.NodeValues.SetEkvent();


        }
        private SequenceCollections CreateSequnce()
        {
            Node n1 = new Node(CarrierOperations.Load, 3);
            Node n2 = new Node(CarrierOperations.Load,2);
            Node n3 = new Node(CarrierOperations.Load, 1);
            Node n4 = new Node(CarrierOperations.PRJobCreate, 3);
            Node n5 = new Node(CarrierOperations.PRJobCreate, 1);
            Node n6 = new Node(CarrierOperations.PRJobCreate, 2);
            Node n7 = new Node(CarrierOperations.CJCreate, 1);
            Node n8 = new Node(CarrierOperations.CJCreate, 2);
            Node n9 = new Node(CarrierOperations.CJCreate, 3);
            collection.Add(n1);
            collection.Add(n2);
            collection.Add(n3);
            collection.Add(n4);
            collection.Add(n5);
            collection.Add(n6);
            collection.Add(n7);
            collection.Add(n8);
            collection.Add(n9);
            return collection;
        }

        private RunTest[] CreateTestObject(Parameters[] parameter)
        {
            RunTest[] test = new RunTest[3];
            test[0] = new RunTest(parameter[0]);

            test[1] = new RunTest(parameter[1]);
            test[2] = new RunTest(parameter[2]);
            //for (int index=0; index <3; index++)
            //{
            //    test[index] = new RunTest(parameter[index]);               
            //}
            return test;
        }

        private Parameters[] CreateParameters()
        {
            Parameters[] p = new Parameters[3];
            p[0] = new Parameters(1, collection);
            p[1] = new Parameters(2, collection);
            p[2] = new Parameters(3, collection);
            return p;

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The function that executed by every thread runnig singe run test case.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="testCase"></param>
        public void ExecuteSingleTest(object testCaseObject)
        {
            RunTest testCase = (testCaseObject as RunTest);
            //Execution of the test case.
            try
            {
                testCase.Exceute(testCase.TestParams);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void SetRest()
        {
            //collection.processcompleted.Set();
            foreach (Parameters t in param)
            {
                t.NodeValues.processcompleted.Set();
            }
        }
        public void ExecuteSingleTest1(object testCaseObject)
        {
            RunTest testCase = (testCaseObject as RunTest);
            //Execution of the test case.
            try
            {
                testCase.RunSimple(testCase.TestParams);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }public enum CarrierOperations
    {
        Load,
        PRJobCreate,
        CJCreate
    }
    public class RunTest
    {
        public static CarrierOperations carrieroperation;
        protected System.IO.StreamWriter file;

        public AutoResetEvent loadoperation;
        public AutoResetEvent PRJobCreate;
        public AutoResetEvent CRJobCreate;
        public Parameters TestParams
        {
            get
            {
                return testParams;
            }
            set
            {
                testParams = value;
            }
        }
         protected Parameters testParams;

        public RunTest(Parameters p)
        {
            TestParams = p;
        }

        protected bool isReachedCollEnd;
        public bool  IsReachedCollEnd
        {
            get
            {
                return isReachedCollEnd;
            }
            set
            {
                isReachedCollEnd = value;
            }
        }
        public void SetEvent()
        {
            testParams.NodeValues.SetEkvent();
        }

        public RunTest()
        {
        }
        public void RunSimple(Parameters p)
        {
            SequenceCollections s = p.NodeValues;            
            testParams = p;
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting before for ID : " + p.LoadPorts.ToString());

            s.processcompleted.WaitOne();
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entered Loop for ID : "+ p.LoadPorts.ToString());

            }

        }

        public void Exceute(Parameters p)
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            testParams = p;
            SequenceCollections coll = p.NodeValues;
            int iterator =0;
            int PortID = 1;
            carrieroperation = CarrierOperations.Load;          
            try
            {
                int threadid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                for (iterator = 0; iterator < coll.NodeList.Count; iterator++)
                {
                    lock (this)
                    {
                        coll.processcompleted.Reset();
                        PortID = coll.NodeList[iterator].LoadPortID;
                    }
                    switch (carrieroperation)
                    {
                        case CarrierOperations.Load:
                            Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : Thread Load port ID " + coll.NodeList[iterator].LoadPortID); 
                            if (PortID == p.LoadPorts)
                            {
                                lock (this)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Entered Load operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString());
                                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                                    SetNextEnum(coll, iterator);
                                    coll.SetEkvent();
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + "Enter (Wait) Load operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());

                                if (!coll.processcompleted.WaitOne())
                                {

                                }
                                Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + " Exit (wait) Load operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());
                                //Console.WriteLine(threadid + "    Exited from Wait Load operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString());

                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(200);
                            //coll.processcompleted.Set();
                            break;
                        case CarrierOperations.PRJobCreate:
                            Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : Thread Load port ID " + coll.NodeList[iterator].LoadPortID); 
                            if (PortID == p.LoadPorts)
                            {
                                lock (this)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Entered PRJobCreate operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString());
                                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                    SetNextEnum(coll, iterator);
                                    coll.SetEkvent();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + "Enter (Wait) Load operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());

                                if (!coll.processcompleted.WaitOne())
                                {

                                }
                                Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + " Exit (wait) Load operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(200);
                           // coll.processcompleted.Set();
                            break;
                        case CarrierOperations.CJCreate:
                            Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : Thread Load port ID " + coll.NodeList[iterator].LoadPortID);
                            if (PortID == p.LoadPorts)
                            {
                                lock (this)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Entered CJCreate operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString());
                                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                    SetNextEnum(coll, iterator);
                                    coll.SetEkvent();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + "Enter (Wait) Load operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());

                                if (!coll.processcompleted.WaitOne())
                                {

                                }
                                Console.WriteLine(threadid + "  : " + " Exit (wait) Load operation for LP:" + p.LoadPorts.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(200);
                            // coll.processcompleted.Set();
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("From Execute"+ ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void SetNextEnum(SequenceCollections coll, int iterator)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                int nextIterator = iterator + 1;
                if (nextIterator == coll.NodeList.Count)
                {
                    carrieroperation = CarrierOperations.Load;
                }
                else
                {

                    Node n = coll.NodeList[nextIterator];
                    carrieroperation = n.OperationName;
                }
            }
        }                 
    }
```